# connect two bluetooth devices at once

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth speaker and a bluetooth mouse..

When I connect the mouse the speaker will start stuttering.  Is this normal?  How should I debug this?  Please advise and I will update this with more information.

Running 14.04 with 4.2 wily kernel.

**UPDATE 1 :**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev bb)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Are you using wifi as well?  Post the result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` if so

Comment: Yes I am using wifi at the same time as well.

Answer (score -1):

We could change the default value of the bluetooth coexistence parameter to see if conditions improve

```
echo "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlbt.conf
```

Reboot and test

If it happens to cause more problems than it solves it can be removed with

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlbt.conf
```

With another reboot

Comment: seems to have no effect